# Configure Scrypt in Gradle for x86 android devices

Tags: android, gradle, scrypt

In my application I need to use a Scrypt library but there's an issue: `scrypt-1.4.0.jar` which is taken from Maven Central refuses to work on x86 architectures.

A hint to solution has been found in this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bitcoinj/B0kOqUVIW24, specifically:

> Yes, the scrypt jar on Maven Central contains native code (lib/*.so). 
>   They really should put this into a separate artifact )-:
>
> Anyway, I'm using

```
 <excludeJarResources>   
 <excludeJarResource>.*\.jar$</excludeJarResource> 
 </excludeJarResources>
```

> in my android-maven-plugin configuration. You need to find something 
>   similar for Gradle.

I use Adroid Studio and have no idea how to achieve the same result in Gradle. The only "solution" I've found is excluding Scrypt library entierly:

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.bitcoinj:bitcoinj-core:0.12.2') {
        exclude module: 'scrypt'
    }
}
```

But of course that only works until I need to use Scrypt in my app. Here's a comment for the code above from the same thread:

> Andreas' code *only* excludes the JAR resources i.e. dynamic library,
>   which means the scrypt library will fall back to a pure Java
>   implementation (much slower).

How can I achieve the same in Gradle? Or alternatively, there was a suggestion to compile the Scrypt native library with the NDK but I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## ***Solution :***

I advice you to recompile the library, i compile my library under linux it's easy, here is how (note it takes a long time to get them compiled)

***Setting up the Environment :***

1. Download and decompress Android NDK
2. Add NDK to Environment Variables (See below)
3. Install android SDK Framework
4. Add Android SDK to Environment Variables (See below)

***Command line to start SDK Manager :***

sdk/tool/androis (sdk manager)

***Adding Android to Environment Variables (Must be done before compiling library) :***

export ANDROID_HOME=/media/.../android-sdk-linux

export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

export PATH=~/bin:/media/.../android-sdk-linux/tools/:/media/.../android-ndk-r10d/:$PATH

***Compiling Library :***

from the project root : run 
`./misc/build-native.sh`

***Android Studio :***

Info : add android studio bin to bin path

Run : from bin dir run studio

***Cleanning Library to recompile them :***

1. Delete following folders
   "\obj"
   "\ovpnlibs"
   "\libs"
2. Recompile library